# How to show an image on hover of a div and then on hover of that image change its CSS properties

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement this:

**Part 1:** On hover of a parent div, display a transparent info icon. (Please find the image attached showing the info icon).[image: Transparent info icon]

**Part 2:** Next, while the parent div is highlighted with green background and on hover of the transparent info icon, I need to change it to an active info icon. (Showing that mouse is hovering on the info icon. Please see the image).[image: Active info icon]

I am able to achieve part 1. But, have trouble in part 2, where hover on the displayed normal info icon doesn't activate the active icon with my CSS. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Here is what I have tried so far. Here is the Html :

```
<div>
    <div id="parent">
        <span class="hover-text">Some Text to hover</span>
        <div class="info-icon"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#parent {
  &:hover {
    background-color: #016E69;
  }
 }
 
 #parent:hover .info-icon { 
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url(../assets/info-icon-transparent.png);
  }

.info-icon{
   background: url(../assets/info-icon-transparent.png);
   width: 24px;
   height: 24px;
   float: left;
   margin-top: 6px;
   display: none;
   margin-left: 12px;
}

 .info-icon:hover {
   background: url(../assets/info-icon-active.png);
}
```

Comment: The selector `#parent:hover .info-icon` has a higher specificity than `.info-icon:hover`, so the background defined in that first rule still wins. Change that second one into `#parent .info-icon:hover`, then they will both have the same specificity, and it should work.

Comment: Or remove the `background` from that `#parent:hover .info-icon` rule - you are setting it with `.info-icon` already, so it is superflous in that first mentioned rule to begin with.

Comment: Thanks CRroe. Tried first solution. It worked!!

Answer (score 0):

Read up on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity, to understand better specificity.

Based on the way you wrote your styles, this:

```
#parent:hover .info-icon { 
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url(../assets/info-icon-transparent.png);
}
```

will take precedence before your last line

```
.info-icon:hover {
   background: url(../assets/info-icon-active.png);
}
```

So update the parent hover to this and just delete *.info-icon:hover*

```
#parent:hover .info-icon { 
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url(../assets/info-icon-active.png);
}
```

ps. also your html is missing a closing div and there are other ways to achieve what you wish to do, using only font icon or only 1 image and on hover changing opacity for example. Less image you use less resources your browser needs to download, faster page loads ;)

Answer (score 0):

```css
@import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css");

button {
  background-color: #016E69;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: none;
}

button i.opacity {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: all 0.2;
}

button:hover i.opacity {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <i class="bi bi-arrow-right"></i> Some text to hover <i class="bi bi-info-circle opacity"></i>
</button>
```